# Approach on creating python global variable

Tags: python-2.7, function, global-variables

I am writing some code of python & selenium webdriver. I got error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable XXX referenced before assignment
```

I was making global assignment in the main function where that object is first initialised. After doing some study i got solution of assigning global variable in function. I made global assignment in one of the function, then i got the error in another function

## So my question is do i really need to assign global assignment in each function or in only first assignment of that global variable.

sample code when i got the error  :

```
class sample:
    driver = None
    def dclose():
        driver.close()
        sys.exit(0)
    def clickLink():
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_link_text('about').click()
        except:
            print "Error: link not found"
    def main():
        global driver
        driver = webBase.Driver(URL)  # another class where i have initalised webdriver with some logger activity.
        clickLink()
        dclose()
```

Now after assigning global in clickLink()

```
class sample:
    driver = None
    def dclose():
        global driver  # does it require  #1
        driver.close()
        sys.exit(0)
    def clickLink():
        global driver # does it require  #2
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_link_text('about').click()
        except:
            print "Error: link not found"
    def main():
        global driver # does it require #3
        driver = webBase.Driver(URL)  # another class where i have initalised webdriver with some logger activity.
        clickLink()
        dclose()
```

## which global assignment is must?

Comment: Each function complained when you didn't declare `driver` as global, and you aren't sure which is needed?

Comment: I have 8 functions in my program for detecting some element and doing some database activity. I solved the problem by declaring global assignment in each function. But my question is  " Is this a right approch? or what i did is just a hack? "

Comment: If that was your question, it would have been good to put in, you know, the actual question.

Comment: Hello Scott, I am newbie . I might not have good way of presenting a question but my question was genuine. Brouke has given me very good explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the constructor to assign it and refer to it by self. Now the driver is a class level variable instead of global. Variables with global scope should be avoided when not required.

```
class Sample:

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webBase.Driver(URL)

    def dclose():
        self.driver.close()
        sys.exit(0)

    def clickLink():
        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('about').click()
        except:
            print("Error: link not found")

    def main():
        clickLink()
        dclose()
```

In order to achieve low coupling, this implementation is better, in which case the driver has to be passed as argument when instantiating the Sample class:

```
class Sample:

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def dclose():
        self.driver.close()
        sys.exit(0)

    def clickLink():
        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('about').click()
        except:
            print("Error: link not found")

    def main():
        clickLink()
        dclose()
```

Comment: Note I changed the class name to Sample instead of sample, according to Python guidelines.

Comment: *Now the driver is a class level variable* - it's an instance level attribute (variable) - not a class level one...

Comment: Jon i didn't get your answer

Comment: Yes, you're right, it is an instance attribute indeed (not 'static' in C# terms). I meant to say it is only accessible from within the instantiated class, but I should have formulated it more accurately.

Comment: Jon meant the driver is limited to the scope of the instantiated class, which is what you need.

Comment: The driver will be the same if you passed the same driver to the constructor, because it is passed by reference. When you pass different instances of the driver, each instantiated Sample class will have it's own driver.